# User removed or users removed?

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar

I noticed that my reputation dropped, and I went to check the topbar. Indeed, there were two user removed notices. However, when I went to the reputation page on my profile, lo and behold, only one "user removed" line, combining the two reputation from the topbar notice.

Here is a combined screenshot:

[image: The two notifications of user removal]

So my question is, what is the source of this discrepancy? Were there one user removed, or two? If one, then why are the two notifications, and if two, why is it only mentioned once?

(I thought that the single mentioning is due to the fact I had reputation by "post" rather than by time, but it doesn't change upon changing that setting either.)

Comment: Before someone jumps to complain that this is a duplicate, note that all the posts asking about "User removed" notice were asking what does it mean, or if their own account was somehow removed. I'm asking about the discrepancy.

Comment: What are the exact time stamps? Are they all the same to the second?

Comment: There are no timestamps in the topbar... Or rather, this is a question for six hours ago. When the timestamp wasn't just "6 hours ago".

Comment: Ah right, sorry. Though actually "There are no timestamps in the topbar... " is not quite true either ;-) There are in the inbox, which is where IIRC I had checked if there are... Strange incoherence. On the part of the site, and on my side too, it must be said.

Comment: I know that all of these events: https://i.imgur.com/EWwHRzy.png correspond to different users (since they were all on the same answer). So I assume these events correspond to two users for you. (It also shows up as a single event in my profile.)